# How to solve this hard combinatoric?

Tags: math, combinatorics

This is a contest problem (ACM ICPC South America 2015), it was the hardest in the problem set.

> **Summary:** Given integers *N* and *K*, count the number of sequences *a* of length *N* consisting of integers *1* ≤ *a*<sub>*i*</sub> ≤ *K*, subject to the condition that for any *x* in that sequence there has to be a pair *i, j* satisfying *i* < *j* and *a*<sub>*i*</sub> = *x* − 1 and *a*<sub>*j*</sub> = *x*, i.e. the last *x* is preceded by *x* − 1 at some point.
>
> **Example:** for *N* = 1000 and *K* = 100 the solution should be congruent to 265428620 modulo (10<sup>9</sup> + 7). Other examples and details can be found in [the problem description](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=866&page=show_problem&problem=4901).

I tried everything in my knowledge, but I need pointers to know how to do it. I even printed some lists with brute force to find the pattern, but I didn't succeed.

I'm looking for an algorithm, or formula that allows me to get to the right solution for this problem. It can be any language.

**EDIT:**

I solved the problem using a formula I found on the internet (someone who explained this problem). However, just because I programmed it, doesn't mean I understand it, so the question remains open. My code is here (the online judge returns *Accepted*):

```c++
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
typedef long long int ll;

ll mod = 1e9+7;
ll memo[5001][5001];

ll dp(int n, int k){

    // K can't be greater than N
    k = min(n, k);

    // if N or K is 1, it means there's only one possible list
    if(n <= 1 || k <= 1) return 1;
    if(memo[n][k] != -1) return memo[n][k];

    ll ans1 = (n-k) * dp(n-1, k-1);
    ll ans2 = k * dp(n-1, k);       
    memo[n][k] = ((ans1 % mod) + (ans2 % mod)) % mod;

    return memo[n][k];
}

int main(){
    int n, q;

    for(int i=0; i<5001; i++)
        fill(memo[i], memo[i]+5001, -1);

    while(scanf("%d %d", &n, &q) == 2){
        for(int i=0; i<q; i++){
            int k;          
            scanf("%d", &k);            
            printf("%s%lld", i==0? "" : " ", dp(n, k)); 
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The most important lines are the recursive call, particularly, these lines

```
ll ans1 = (n-k) * dp(n-1, k-1);
ll ans2 = k * dp(n-1, k);       
memo[n][k] = ((ans1 % mod) + (ans2 % mod)) % mod;
```

Comment: You should put the whole definition of what you need on this page. Links to you question content are considered bad. How do you want to see the result? For example can Python code be an answer?

Comment: Yes, any code or formula that finds the answer is an answer I'd appreciate. I just want to know how should I go about to solve or analyze it.

Comment: The problem is very complicated I spent 15 minutes trying to understand the problem and failed. Maybe I will try it later.

Comment: Why when N=3 and K=2 the answer is 5? The following sequences apply: 121,112,122,212

Comment: @keiv.fly also 111 is a valid sequence ;)

Comment: n-k and k look like C(n,k) calculation. That is all I can tell. You can try your luck in http://math.stackexchange.com/ There should be some theory behind the recursive formula.

Comment: I get it now. There exists a bijection between just a bit sorted lists, and the set of permutations of 1,2,3,4,..n that have k ascents (adjacent pairs of numbers where the first is less than the second). The cardinality of this set is known to be computed using Euler's triangle (same recursive formula). We can't compute cardinality of "just a bit sorted lists" directly, but since there is a bijection, we just compute the Euler one, and the result is the same. The problem with this kind of problems is that you can't easily prove there is a bijection.

Answer (score 0):

Here I show the brute force algorithm for the problem in python. It works for small numbers, but for very big numbers it takes too much time. For N=1000 and K=5 it is already infeasible (Needs more than 100 years time to calculate)(In C it should also be infeasible as C is only 100 times faster than Python). So the problem actually forces you to find a shortcut.

```
import itertools

def checkArr(a,K):
    for i in range(2,min(K+1,max(a)+1)):
        if i-1 not in a:
            return False
        if i not in a:
            return False
        if a.index(i-1)>len(a)-1-a[::-1].index(i):
            return False
    return True

def num_sorted(N,K):
    result=0
    for a in itertools.product(range(1,K+1), repeat=N):
        if checkArr(a,K):
            result+=1
    return result

num_sorted(3,10)
```

It returns 6 as expected.